# Laravel Queue Failed Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, queue, supervisord, beanstalkd

I was trying to record some data from other table when the jobs fails. It works great in failed jobs table but I cant get the `Queue::failing(function($connection, $job, $data)` to work every time the job failed. I did try to put it in `global.php` but no luck.

Another question is what does the `$job` return? An object or just the job id?

Comment: ok ...with queues which queue driver are you using is it Beanstalkd, please post some of your code you have tried

Comment: I am using beanstalk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work on `global php`. Its causing an error, just changed following:

```
Queue::failing(function($connection, $job, $data)
```

To:

```
Queue::failing(function($connection, $job)
```

Answer (score 19):

You should call queue:work with --tries param, for ex:

```
$ php artisan queue:work sqs --tries=1
```

Without this params, your job will never get failed.

But remember to config you failed table.

1) Create migration file:

```
$ php artisan queue:failed-table
```

2) Run migrate to create table

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

3) In queue.php you need to config you 'failed' table. Ex:

```
'failed' => array(
    'database' => 'pgsql', 'table' => 'failed_jobs',
),
```

Now, when the job gets failed, it will insert it into *failed_jobs* table.

Just run `php artisan queue:failed` to get the failed list.